# Como exibir os erros do ModelState quando o POST é feito por AJAX?

Tags: javascript, validação, asp.net-core

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em asp.net core 2.0. Possuo uma div com o asp-validation-summary para a exibição dos erros do modelState.

segue:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All"
  class="validation-summary alert alert-danger alert-dismissable ">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">
              &times;
              </span>
            </button>
            <h4>O formulário possui erros:</h4>
</div>
```

Tenho também um javascript que verifica se existe erros e exibe a div ou escode.
Segue:

```
$(function () {
$('.validation-summary-errors').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('alert');
    $(this).addClass('alert-danger');
});

$('form').each(function () {
    $(this).find('div.form-group').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('span.field-validation-error').length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('has-error');
            $(this).find('span.field-validation-error').
               removeClass('field-validation-error');
        }
    });
});
```

});

E no controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(SetorVM vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _setorAppService.Adicionar(vm);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "O seu formulário possui erros! Corrija-os para continuar.");
        }

        return View(vm);
    }
```

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

MINHA DIFICULDADE:
Tenho uma página onde trabalho com uma lista que vou adicionando itens via javascript. Então realizo o POST via AJAX, e no controller recebo os dados normalente e o modelstate também faz as validações. O problema é que se o modelState não for válido e eu retornar a view não está aparecendo os erros...

Tem algo a ver o POST Ser via ajax???

Segue o código:

```
var url = "/Material/Create";

$.ajax({
    url: url
    , type: "POST"
    , datatype: "json"
    , headers: headersadr
    , data: {xxxxxxx }
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.resultado > 0) {
        }
        else {
            var divItens = $("#divValidationSummaryShow");
            divItens.empty();
            divItens.show();
            divItens.html(data);

        }
    }
});
```

CONTROLLER:

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _materialAppService.Adicionar(vm);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
             ModelState.AddModelError("", "O seu formulário possui erros! Corrija-os para continuar.");
        }
        return View(vm);
```

E tenho como resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que tenho que fazer para a exibição correta da página???
Também aceito outras forma de fazer a validação...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode retornar um `Json` contendo os erros do `ModelState`

**Action**

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     return Json(new { success = false, errors = ModelState.Values.Where(i => i.Errors.Count > 0) });
 }
```

**Ajax**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        headers: headersadr,
        data: {
            xxxxxxx
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.errors.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.errors.length; i++) {
                    var error = response.errors[i];
                    //Aplique os erros na sua div validation-summary
                }
            } else {
                var divItens = $("#divValidationSummaryShow");
                divItens.empty();
                divItens.show();
                divItens.html(data);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado Netinho, vou testar!

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua resposta. É possível me mostrar como ficaria o  $.ajax completo?

Comment: @RafaelArthur editei a resposta e inclui o ajax completo. Att.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!